# Converting mp4 to mp3 and audio coming out "repeating" in Python (moviepy)

Tags: python, moviepy

Well, i was trying to make a program that you could download mp4 and mp3 files from youtube.
The mp4 part is alright, but the mp3 part... ouch
Since yesterday i was trying to do sometype of converting mechanism (i'm new to coding) that took the mp4 file that i downloaded and then convert it to mp3, after hours and hours i found way that could do it in a way that i can hear the audio (simply changing the .mp4 to .mp3 didnt work).

But theres a slight problem, after about 4 seconds of audio, it starts repeating itself, just like a scratched cd, and i have no ideia of how to fix it.

```
import os
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import *

link = input("Coloque o link: ")
yt = YouTube(link)

def removespecialchars(string):
    allowed_chars = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-()[]{}\\:')
    cleaned_string = ''.join(char for char in string if char in allowed_chars)
    cleaned_string += ".mp3"
    return cleaned_string


print("Title: ", yt.title)
print("Views: ", yt.views)

while True:
    formatChoice = input("Você quer mp3 ou mp4? ").upper()
    if formatChoice == "MP4":
        youtubeDownloadMP4 = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        youtubeDownloadMP4.download("D:\\Videos\\YoutubeVideo")
        print("Seu vídeo foi instalado")
        break
    elif formatChoice == "MP3":
        youtubeDownloadMP3 = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        caminho = ("D:\\Music")
        mp3filename = removespecialchars(yt.title)
        mp3path = os.path.join(caminho, mp3filename)
        youtubeDownloadMP3.download(caminho, filename=mp3filename)

        audioClip = AudioFileClip(mp3path)
        audioClip.write_audiofile(mp3path, codec='libmp3lame')

        print("Seu mp3 foi instalado")
        break
    else:
        print("Escreva 'mp3' ou 'mp4' burro")
```

(something are in portuguese, dont worry bout it)

expecting it to work as normally, the mp3 file (already converted) started repeating about 4 secs

Comment: btw, i tested in other links and it always at about 4 secs that it starts glitching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why the audio crashes after the conversion according to your provided information. (Maybe it's an encoding/decoding issue?)

Instead of using `moviepy`, you could try `ffmpeg`, which may be more robust and can automatically determine which codec to use. In this case, just replace  the following lines in your code:

```py
audioClip = AudioFileClip(mp3path)
audioClip.write_audiofile(mp3path, codec='libmp3lame')
```

to this:

```py
ffmpeg.input(mp3path).output(mp3path.replace('.mp3', '_convert.mp3')).run()
```

p.s. In order to make use of `ffmpeg` in Python, you need to install it with `pip install ffmpeg-python` and add `import ffmpeg` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: tysm!! your solution did work, probably a problem with moviepy